# Ansible list not ordered

Tags: python-2.7, ansible

I have a list I'm looping over, the issue is it gives a weird order.

param.yml file:

```
my_list:
  a: val1
  b: val2
  c: val3
  d: val3
```

Here my simple debug loop:

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ my_list | list }}"
```

Here the output:

```
ok: [host] => (item=a) => {
    "msg": "a"
}
ok: [host] => (item=c) => {
    "msg": "c"
}
ok: [host] => (item=b) => {
    "msg": "b"
}
ok: [host] => (item=d) => {
    "msg": "d"
}
```

I'm using ansible 2.10 with python 2.7.5:

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.10.2
  config file = /home/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ansible/library']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:16:51) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

The problem when I switch to python3, it is working as expected:

```
ok: [host] => (item=a) => {
    "msg": "a"
}
ok: [host] => (item=b) => {
    "msg": "b"
}
ok: [host] => (item=c) => {
    "msg": "c"
}
ok: [host] => (item=d) => {
    "msg": "d"
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade the environment to python3 and I need the list to be in the same order as in the param.yml file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable *my_list* is not a list. It's a dictionary. There is no guarantee in which order a dictionary's keys will be iterated. Use [*sort*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#sort) filter. For example,

```yaml
  my_keys: "{{ my_list|list|sort }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  my_keys: [a, b, c, d]
```

---

Q: ***"I need to iterate over it in the same order as it is in the param.yml"***

A: It's the wrong data structure for a use case. [YAML mapping is an unordered set](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#mapping//). You can't *"iterate over it in the same order"* because there is no order. Use a list of keys. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}: {{ my_list[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_keys }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'a: val1'
  msg: 'b: val2'
  msg: 'c: val3'
  msg: 'd: val4'
```

- The results are strings. Create JSON if you want to get dictionaries

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: '{ "{{ item }}": "{{ my_list[item] }}" }'
      loop: "{{ my_keys }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg:
    a: val1
  msg:
    b: val2
  msg:
    c: val3
  msg:
    d: val4
```

- The next option is using the filter *dict2items* and converting the dictionary to a list. Use the filters [sort](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.sort) and sort the list by the attribute *key*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list|dict2items|sort(attribute='key') }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg:
    key: a
    value: val1
  msg:
    key: b
    value: val2
  msg:
    key: c
    value: val3
  msg:
    key: d
    value: val4
```

- But, if you want to keep the order, the simplest option is to put the data into a list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
      vars:
        my_list:
          - a: val1
          - b: val2
          - c: val3
          - d: val4
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_list:
      a: val1
      b: val2
      c: val3
      d: val4

    my_keys: "{{ my_list|list|sort }}"
    my_key2: "{{ my_list.keys()|sort }}"
    
  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: my_keys|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: my_key2|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}: {{ my_list[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ my_keys }}"
      tags: t1

    - debug:
        msg: '{ "{{ item }}": "{{ my_list[item] }}" }'
      loop: "{{ my_keys }}"
      tags: t2

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list|dict2items|sort(attribute='key') }}"
      tags: t3

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
      vars:
        my_list:
          - a: val1
          - b: val2
          - c: val3
          - d: val4
      tags: t4
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the problem `my_list` I cannot sort it, I need to iterate over it in the same order as it is in the `param.yml` file (I just simplified it here)

Comment: There is no solution to this problem. [YAML mapping s an **unordered set**](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#mapping//). i.e. You can't *"iterate over it in the same order"* because there is no order.

Comment: thanks, this file contains dict of objects, and there's another automation that inserts into this file at the end, I need to get the last 10 objects inserted via ansible, converting it to list and get the last 10 wasn't usefully (due to this random order), any idea how I can accomplish that?

Comment: You'll have to parse the file on your own.

Comment: @sadok-f building on this answer, what you can do is to have a dict containing both the value and a field you'd sort on (sorry that's the JSON notation, than fits better in the comment that the YAML one) e.g. `{'a': { 'value': 'val1', 'added_at': '2020-10-07 08:00:00' } }` and then sort on this `added_at` fields

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I'd do that if the project is new or have few objects, but currently the yml file is quite huge and used by many components.
I think I'll go to parse the file on my own and get the last objects.