# referencing variables from defaults/main.yml in ansible role

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a role setup as follows

roles/test/task/main.yml

```
- name: Generate people files
  template: src=test.j2 dest=/tmp/{{ item.name }}.cfg
  loop: "{{people}}"
```

roles/test/template/test.j2

```
First Var: {{ item.var1 }}
Second Var: {{ item.var2 }}
```

roles/test/vars/main.yml

```
---
people:
        - name: TheSimpsons
          var1: homer
          var2: simpson

        - name: StarWars
          var1: han
          var2: solo
```

roles/test/defaults/main.yml

```
people:
   - var2: skywalker
```

my playbook

```
 - hosts: localhost
   roles:
    - test
```

When I run my playbook everything works as expect.  I get two new files in /tmp with the correct text.  However if I remove this var2 line from my vars/main.yml file...

```
          var2: solo
```

I would expect the var2 value from my defaults/main.yml to show up in the output, but all I get is this error

```
failed: [localhost] (item={u'var1': u'han', u'name': u'StarWars'}) => {
    "changed": false,
    "item": {
        "name": "StarWars",
        "var1": "han"
    },
    "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'var2'"
}
```

I have tried formatting my defaults/main.yml about 10 different ways but get the same error each time.

If I setup a test that doesn't loop and defaults/main.yml and vars/main.yml are flat "key: value" pairs I can get it to pull values from defaults/main/yml just fine.

Something about the looping I'm just not getting.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more options on how to combine the lists' items. For example, rename the defaults, e.g.

```yaml
people_defaults:
   - var2: skywalker
```

Rename the vars too and create the list

```yaml
people_vars:
  - name: TheSimpsons
    var1: homer
    var2: simpson
  - name: StarWars
    var1: than
people: "{{ people_defaults|product(people_vars)|map('combine')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
people:
  - name: TheSimpsons
    var1: homer
    var2: simpson
  - name: StarWars
    var1: han
    var2: skywalker
```

---

**Details of the role**

```yaml
shell> tree roles/test/
roles/test/
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── tasks
│   └── main.yml
└── vars
    └── main.yml

3 directories, 3 files
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test/defaults/main.yml 
people_defaults:
  - var2: skywalker
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test/vars/main.yml 
people_vars:
  - name: TheSimpsons
    var1: homer
    var2: simpson
  - name: StarWars
    var1: han
people: "{{ people_defaults|product(people_vars)|map('combine')|list }}"
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/test/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: people
```

---

**Error: combine expects dictionaries**

If you run the code on Ansible 2.9 or older you'll see the error

> {"msg": "|combine expects dictionaries, got ({'var2': 'skywalker'},
> {'name': 'TheSimpsons', 'var1': 'homer', 'var2': 'simpson'})"}

Fix the problem by mapping the tuples to the lists. This fix is upwards compatible.

```yaml
people: "{{ people_defaults|product(people_vars)|map('list')|map('combine')|list }}"
```

---

Q: ***"Combination of the lists does not preserve the hierarchy of variables."***

A: You're combining dictionaries. A dictionary(mapping) in YAML is an **unordered** set of key/value node pairs. See [Mapping](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#3211-nodes). The sorting is up to you. See [Ansible list not ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247873/ansible-list-not-ordered/64248023#64248023).

Comment: Is there an option where you don't combine the lists?  For my role the vars/main.yml is generated dynamically through automation and I would like to avoid adding that extra step.  Can I get this to work by changing syntax in the defaults/main.yml file?

Comment: Sure. Put the expression into the defaults.

Comment: I cut and paste your example into a role and ran it and got the following error:  combine expects dictionaries, got ({'var2': 'skywalker'}, {'name': 'TheSimpsons', 'var1': 'homer', 'var2': 'simpson'})"

Comment: If you run the code on Ansible 2.9 or older fix it. I added the fix.

Comment: BINGO!  That worked!  I guess I should have identified my Ansible version (Ansible 2.9.6) in the original question.  My bad.  I appreciate you sticking with it finding a solution.

Comment: Doing some further testing I notice that combining the lists does not preserve the hierarchy of variables, meaning if I add a variable to vars/main.yml that exists in defaults/main.yml it does not honor it.  Is there a way to get the best of both worlds (combining and hierarchy).  I might have the need to overwrite defaults either from the command line or from vars/main.yml.

Comment: YAML dictionaries are unordered. The sorting is up to you. I added a new section with details.

Comment: I think I am going to post a new question to further this topic as I feel it is starting to stray from the original question/solution in this thread.  I am new to ansible and your responses here have helped me tremendously from what I learned here I feel I can ask a more succinct question.  Thanks you!!